# "image data type" in sql equivalent in vba to be use in ADODB CreateParameter

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to pass an "image type data" as a parameter (LongDescription(image,null) as declared in SQL) in my SQL stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spselConvertImageTEST] 
  @ReportedByCountry nvarchar(10) OUTPUT,
  @ReportId nvarchar(10) OUTPUT,
  @LongDescription image OUTPUT
```

And I am trying to receive it in access VBA like this:

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    .CommandText = "dbo.spselConvertImageTEST"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandTimeout = 300
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ReportedByCountry", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 10)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ReportId", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 10)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("LongDescription", adBinary, adParamOutput)
    .Execute
End With
```

When trying to create the third parameter I receive this error:

Run-time error '3708'
Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

Can anybody be so kind as to help me out here, please?

Comment: If you link to the table from access - it will probably show up as an OLE Object.

Comment: Try `.CreateParameter("LongDescription", adVarBinary, adParamOutput)`

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson I tried adVarBinary =( same error

Comment: `.CreateParameter("LongDescription", adVarBinary, adParamOutput, 2147483646)` seems to work.

Comment: **DON'T USE image**. It's deprecated for almost 10 years, the documentation is *very explicit about it*. Use `varbinary(max)`. The corresponding parameter type isn't `adBinary` either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers I decided to do it this way:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "dbo.spselConvertImageTEST", CurrentProject.Connection

With rs
    .MoveFirst

    Do While Not .EOF
        Me.oleLongDescription = .Fields("LongDescription")                               
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

**Gord Thompson** thanks for your last suggestion too but unfortunately it did not work either I received the following error:

Run-time error '-2147024882(8007000e)
No enough storage is available to complete this operation.